# Php "upload_max_filesize" is not changing after changes in php.ini file

Tags: php

I have changed

```
upload_max_filesize = 256M
post_max_size = 257M
memory_limit = 258M
```

and set `file_uploads = On` in **php.ini** file. After that I checked **phpinfo.php** and it is still showing
`upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 48M 
memory_limit = 64M`. After that I created a file called **.user.ini** with same code as php.ini and uploaded it. After that I checked phpinfo.php and my set value are appeared correctly under **"Local Value"** and in **"Master Value"** it is showing the old value. What to change. Plz Help!!

Comment: You have to restart the Server and check again

Comment: Make sure that you've changed the correct php.ini file (many systems have different ini files for different SAPIs (web or CLI).... phpinfo() should tell you what ini file you need to update..... and make sure you've rebooted the web server

Comment: if it is local server.. please restart machine and check again once

Comment: Hello Arun!!! Actually, I do not know how to restart the server. Can you plz help?

Comment: are you using xampp or wamp ?

Comment: I wonder why you have choosen `256M`, `257M` ...

Comment: if you can't restart the server.. please restart the machine

Comment: Arun, I am using LAMP server.

Comment: hek2mgl, the matter is not that what value I used. The thing that bothering me why it is not changing.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Run.2C_Stop.2C_Test.2C_And_Restart_Apache

Answer (score -1):

You are changing the values of upload max filesize,post max size and memory beyond the maximum allowable limit.

Below are the maximum allowable size for each one of them.

upload_max_filesize = 40MB

post_max_size = 40MB

memory_limit = 128MB

Comment: Changed the values as you said but, still the same problem arised. Local Value changed to 40M but Master value is still 32 M

Comment: Please restart your server again

Comment: Since when did these "maximum allowable limits" exist? While some hosts may apply restrictions, these aren't PHP restrictions at all, so I'm afraid that you are factually wrong here in suggesting that PHP Imposes these "maximum allowable limits"

Comment: Hello Mark. I am using Godaddy and in my phpinfo.php the Loaded Configuration File path shows /usr/local/lib/php.ini and I am not getting this. I have placed the php.ini file under public_html folder. Is that ok or not?

Comment: If `phpinfo()` shows that the loaded configuration file is `/usr/local/lib/php.ini` then that's the file that you need to edit; you don't arbitrarily stick a file called php.ini in some arbitrary folder, and then hope that PHP will find it and pick it up